# MS Excel 2010 Identify peaks in a data set, select its previous values and get a chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, search, find

I have a set of data about with approximatively 25500 cells, all contained in one column. 
The data has a series of peaks that occurs, and I need to identify the 2nd peak (and the 4th, the 6th, and so on where present). 
I have than to consider the previous 200 data points of the 2nd peak (corresponding to the previous 20 seconds) in order to get a data range for a chart.
When the values are identified, I have to store it in another column and take it as reference for the chart.
At present I do it manually, looking on the chart and using the Ms Office tool “find and search”…
Here linked the example file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B224nfA5sDRCd3huRzlEelB4cXM
I hope that it will possible to find a function to do automatically but I don't know how to do that in excel.
Thanks for the attention.
Alessandro

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Alessandro - just because I'm an Engineer and a sucker for analyzing data ...

You correctly broke your problem down into three parts:

1. Identify the peaks
2. Move the data from before the peaks to a different tab
3. Plot the data on each tab

**Identify the peaks**

Peak identification is a science unto itself, and there are many methods available, and many free pieces of code out there.

Here, I choose to do it simply with spreadsheet formulae. It will need some "tuning" if/when you apply it to different data.

Below, Cell `C3` (and filled down) is a simple peak detection based on rate of change of the variable. `tol` is a reference to Cell `F2`, and is the minimum rate of change needed to detect a peak. `PkHeight` is a reference to Cell `G2`, and is the minimum value of the variable needed to detect a peak. These can be adjusted to tune the sensitivity of the calculation.

This calculation identifies many peaks - a further calculation is needed to filter for the peaks of interest.

Cell `C3` ... `=IF(AND(B3-B2>tol,B3-B4>=0,B3>PkHeight),1,0)`

Below, Cell D3 (and filled down) eliminates consecutive peaks such that the first peak is identified as "the" peak. `LookBack` is a reference to Cell `H2`. It can be used to tune this calculation. If a peak was detected in the current row, and a peak was detected in the previous `LookBack` rows, the current peak will be rejected.

Cell `D3` ... `=IF(AND(C3=1,MAX(C2:OFFSET(C2,MAX(2,ROW()-LookBack)-ROW(),0))=0),1,0)`

Cell `I2` is a the sum of Column D. `=SUM(D2:D25569)` - it shows we have identifed 6 unique peaks.

[image]

**Move the data from before the peaks to a different tab**

The VBA sub below does the following:

1. Puts the data in an array for faster processing. If you change the arrangement of your source data (put it in different columns, this part will need to be modified.
2. Identifies every second peak (e.g. 2, 4, 6)
3. Creates or cleans up a worksheet to hold the new data. Part of this uses a function `WSExists`. [This code was found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists).
4. Extracts the 200 data points from before the peak into another array. The variable `tarRows` is used to specify 200 data points.
5. The extracted data is moved from the array to the pertinent worksheet.
6. Plot's are made.

Below is the `ExtractPeakData` code ...

```
Sub ExtractPeakData()
Dim srcSht As Worksheet, tarSht As Worksheet
Dim srcRng As Range, tarRng As Range
Dim PeakRng As Range
Dim tarCht As ChartObject
Dim PeakArr() As Variant, srcArr() As Variant, tarArr() As Variant
Dim tarShtName As String
Dim lstRow As Long
Dim PeakCnt As Long, tarRows As Long
Dim iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long, kLoop As Long
Dim loopStart As Long

' initialize

Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
lstRow = srcSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set srcRng = srcSht.Range(srcSht.Cells(1, 1), srcSht.Cells(lstRow, 2))
Set PeakRng = srcSht.Range(srcSht.Cells(1, 4), srcSht.Cells(lstRow, 4))

srcArr = srcRng.Value
PeakArr = PeakRng.Value
PeakCnt = 0
tarRows = 200 + 1 ' one row for the header


' Find the even numbered peaks
For iLoop = LBound(PeakArr, 1) To UBound(PeakArr, 1)
    If PeakArr(iLoop, 1) = 1 Then PeakCnt = PeakCnt + 1
    If PeakArr(iLoop, 1) = 1 And PeakCnt Mod 2 = 0 Then

' Create or clean up a sheet for the data and chart
        tarShtName = "PeakData" & PeakCnt
        If Not WSExists(tarShtName) Then
            Set tarSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            tarSht.Name = tarShtName
        Else
            Set tarSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tarShtName)
            tarSht.Cells.Clear
            For Each tarCht In tarSht.ChartObjects
                tarCht.Delete
            Next tarCht
        End If

        loopStart = iLoop - tarRows
        If loopStart < 2 Then loopStart = 2
        ReDim tarArr(1 To iLoop - loopStart, 1 To UBound(srcArr, 2))

' put the header row in
        For kLoop = 1 To UBound(tarArr, 2)
            tarArr(1, kLoop) = srcArr(1, kLoop)
        Next kLoop
' put the data rows in
        For jLoop = loopStart + 1 To iLoop - 1
            For kLoop = 1 To UBound(tarArr, 2)
                tarArr(jLoop - loopStart + 1, kLoop) = srcArr(jLoop, kLoop)
            Next kLoop
        Next jLoop
        Set tarRng = tarSht.Range(tarSht.Cells(1, 1), tarSht.Cells(tarRows, 2))
        tarRng.Value = tarArr

' plot the data on each target sheet
        PlotPeakData (tarShtName)
    End If
Next iLoop

' clean up
Erase PeakArr
Erase tarArr
Erase srcArr
Set tarRng = Nothing
Set srcRng = Nothing
Set tarSht = Nothing
Set srcSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

... and below is the `WSExistss` code ...

```
Function WSExists(myStr As String) As Boolean
' From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists
Dim ws As Worksheet
  WSExists = False
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If myStr = ws.Name Then
      WSExists = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next ws
End Function
```

**Plot the data on each tab**

The loop in `ExtractPeakData` is used to manage the "on each tab" part. The Sub `PlotPeakData` is the routine that generates the individual plots.

It is simple, and the comments tell it all ...

```
Sub PlotPeakData(PkDataName As String)
Dim PkDataSht As Worksheet
Dim PkDataCht As ChartObject
Dim lstRow As Long

' initial
If Not WSExists(PkDataName) Then Exit Sub
Set PkDataSht = Worksheets(PkDataName)
lstRow = PkDataSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

' create the chart and position it
Set PkDataCht = PkDataSht.ChartObjects.Add( _
        PkDataSht.Range("E2").Left, _
        PkDataSht.Range("E2").Top, _
        PkDataSht.Range("M2").Left - PkDataSht.Range("E2").Left, _
        PkDataSht.Range("E17").Top - PkDataSht.Range("E2").Top)

With PkDataCht.Chart
' add the data to it
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = PkDataSht.Range("B1")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = PkDataSht.Range("A2:A" & lstRow)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = PkDataSht.Range("B2:B" & lstRow)
' add the titles to it
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = PkDataSht.Range("B1").Value
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = PkDataSht.Range("A1").Value
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = PkDataSht.Range("B1")
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
' do the gridlines
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .HasLegend = False
' do other formatting here ...
End With

End Sub
```

**Results**

Below are screen captures after running `ExtractPeakData`.

For the second peak ...

[image]

For the fourth peak ...

[image]

For the sixth peak ...

[image]